# How to make a automatically updated TextView based on date and user input?

Tags: java, android

I have an idea, but is quite new to both programming and Android Studio and need help from you guys to solve it.

I would like the user to write a number and a day in the month, e.g. 100000 and 15. The app should know how many days it is left to next time it is 15 and based on that count up to 100000, the value should be visible in a TextView and update automatically everyday.

E.g. Today is the 21 day of the month and it is 22 days left to the next time it is 15. Between 15th February and 15th March is it 28 days, and it has gone 6 days so far. 100000 / 28 * 6 = 21428,5714.

Any ideas/suggestions to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read up on the use of broadcast receivers and tweak it to suit your purpose.